# How to configure beacons through an iOS application?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

I am new to BLE and beacons technologies , I am now able to detect beacons , and use them in app , it works fine .

My company has produced our own beacons , having UDIDs , Major , Minor etc.

Now , I want to develop an app through which i can reconfigure those (my company ) beacons , as we do for Gimbal & Kontakt managerial application .

In brief I want to develop an managerial app to configure our own beacons.

Please guide me suitable right approach to achieve this  so that I do not research on wrong path .

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you want to change the data contained in your beacons ? If so, did you try [LightBlue](https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/lightblue-bluetooth-low-energy/id557428110?mt=8) ? Does it fit your needs ? If not, you will have to work with [CoreBluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/) framework (not CoreLocation) to access and modify your beacon's CBService and CBCharacteristic with CBPeripheralDelegate.

Comment: ryancrunchi i will go through those links , thank you !

Comment: You're welcome. I don't have time to tell you more but the key thing is to use CoreBluetooth to access all what you need in a bluetooth peripheral. This is a trap that CoreLocation beacons delegates hides all peripherals data except UDID, major and minor